# foreach with option select post value

Tags: php, forms

I am doing the verification of a form, I want to choose the selected value if there is an error, the problem is that something is working wrong because when you send the form you add "selected" to all.

```
foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
echo "
<option value='".(!empty($_POST["producto_categoria"]) ? $categoria['hijo_id']." selected" : $categoria['hijo_id'])."'>
    {$categoria['padre_nombre']} > {$categoria['hijo_nombre']}
</option>
";
}
```

**Before sending the form:**

[image]

**After submitting the form:**

[image]

If the form is sent but there is an error in another part of the form, I want the selected option to be remembered in order to continue with the form.

Any idea where is my error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cant get selected option after form submission wrong unless you save the value of selected option or unless you send the selected value from validation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [ternary](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) logic is invalid. Here's a corrected version of your code, which also includes calls to sanitize via [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST['producto_categoria'] ) ) {
    $producto_categoria = (string) $_POST['producto_categoria'];
}
foreach ( $categorias as $categoria ) {
    echo '<option' . // Possibly the selected option.
            ' value="' . htmlspecialchars( $categoria['hijo_id'] ) . '"' .
            ( $categoria['hijo_id'] === $producto_categoria ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>' .
            htmlspecialchars( $categoria['padre_nombre'] . ' > ' . $categoria['hijo_nombre'] ) .
         '</option>';
}
```